# Blazor Micro frontends

Tags: reactjs, architecture, blazor, blazor-server-side, micro-frontend

hope everybody is doing great!

I'd like to know if there's a way to append reactJS frontends to an existing blazor SSR (server side rendering) application.

I've already delved into the depths of internet searching for any content that could help me with that, but without success.

I see that there are two approaches, one of them is appending in build time and the other one is in runtime. I'd prefer to do it in runtime, but if you know how to do in another way, that's also useful.

Thanks in advance!